# preview before printing with node webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

Is it possible to have a preview page before printing on node webkit ?

```
var printItem = document.getElementsByClassName("print");
printItem[0].onclick = function () {
    win.print({
        printer: '',
        headerFooterEnabled: false

    })
};
```

I can only launch a silent print!
Or is it possible to print a PDF file and open it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add "Save as Pdf" in the printer option :

```
win.print({
    printer: 'Save as Pdf',
    headerFooterEnabled: false

})
```

As simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

window.print()

or create a print preview page and use the win.print({}) from there

Answer (score 0):

I tried as t.c says, but a windows popup always asking for pdf path.
Finaly i solve my problem just with a simple:
`window.print();`